# Set and Save User Control Properties

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a test application which has a user control in it. now on run time user can change the properties of user control. however when i close the application and start again it comes back to the default values. 
How to save the properties values on run time ?

Comment: In case u use visual studio read: [Using Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`  Otherwise, please show us some code.